# TexStudio not syncing Tex and pdf (go to source)

Tags: forward-inverse-search

I'm having a sporadic problem with synctex. 'Go to source' (i.e.from pdf to tex) only gets to within about a page of the correct location in some files, but in others it is spot on. Any idea what might be going on?

NB I am compiling with 'synctex=1' and I've tried deleting *.synctex and *.synctex.rar in the working directory. (Textudio 2.11 / Windows 10)

Thanks in advance, Chris.

Comment: The compressed synchronisation files are compressed with `rar`, not`gzip` on your system?

Comment: Sorry - .gz. Same icon :-)

Comment: It was just out of curiosity. That said, which pdf viewer do you use?

Comment: The built-in viewer

Comment: Why don't you try with `SumatraPDF` as an external pdf viewer? It also manages .synctex files.